# What is the Difference between PrintWriter and DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, chat

I'm working on a chat room application for android. I read different tutorials; some of them use PrintWriter to send data and some of them use DataOutputStream. What is the difference between these two? Which one is better for a chat app?

Comment: When you talk about a chat application, are you referring to writing to screen or sending data over the network?

Comment: sending data for communication over the network not write on screen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From java docs

A [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) lets an application write primitive Java data types to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then use a data input stream to read the data back in.

[PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream. This class implements all of the print methods found in PrintStream. It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program should use unencoded byte streams.

In one sentence the difference is:

**OutputStreams are meant for binary data. Writers (including PrintWriter) are meant for text data**

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter` converts everything to Ascii format. For example:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("./test.txt"));        
        for (Integer word: words) {
            pw.println(word);
        }
```

in this block of code, by calling `pw.printin(word)`; no matter what the type of word is (which is integer here), program converts it to ASCII format and stores it. As a result, when we want to retrieve that stored data and read it again, program have to do another type changing from text to original format! -which is not good in term of time efficiency!
For instance, if that word is an integer, after storing that into a file (which is text now), program has to change its format from String to integer when it is going to retrieve that!

But, `DataOutPutStream` makes everything much easier since it stores the data into bytes by keeping data type. So, when we run bellow block, program stored integer as byte and when it want to retrieve that it does not need any change of type. It's stored as integer and retrieved as integer too. So, it is much faster!

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(new File("test2.txt")));

    for (Integer word: words) {
        dos.writeUTF(word);   
 }
dos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `DataOutputStream` and `PrintWriter` are two classes in java.io.

```
class DataOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream implements DataOutput {
}
```

`Javadoc` says

> "A data output stream lets an application write primitive Java data types to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then use a data input stream to read the data back in."

```
 public class PrintWriter extends Writer {
 }
```

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream. This class implements all of the print methods found in PrintStream.  It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program should use unencoded byte streams.

Comment: which is better for chat app ?

Comment: No. `PrintWriter` and `PrintStream` will swallow exceptions that you need to know about in network programming. I wouldn't use either of them. If you want characters, use `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader`.