# Why does this piece of code write/print all 0.0 instead of different random numbers?

Tags: java, file, random

I'm trying to generate random numbers 
and write them to a file, then print them. 
Instead all zeros such as this 0.0 are printed by line in the console
and in the file its written in ASCII code.

I have already tied using different java input classes and using the random number generator.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        makefile(10, "inputHW02.txt");

        double[] sizearray0 = new double[10];
        int i = 0;
        Scanner inFile;

        inFile = new Scanner(new File("inputHW02.txt"));

        while (inFile.hasNextDouble()) {
            sizearray0[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < sizearray0.length; r++)
            System.out.println(sizearray0[r]);

        inFile.close();
    }

    public static void makefile(double n, String filename) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(writer);
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dos.writeInt((int) 60);
            ;

        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

I expect the file and output console should have random numbers separated on a new
line such as
10.0
23.0
1.0
and so forth.

Comment: You never use `rand`...

Comment: Also, if you expect to find double values written as strings and separated by spaces, then that's what you should write, with a PrintWriter for example, to the file.

Comment: @Zephyr it's funny cause it's true

Comment: @Zephyr , read in the post the things I’ve tried and I quote “ I have already tried using different Java input classes and using the random number generator”. I just did not delete that line from before.

Comment: @ave4496 it’s funny because you didn’t read either.

Comment: Learn to post better questions and drop the attitude. We're not going to take the time to guess what you **meant** to post.

Comment: @Zephyr Again, I posted what I already tried, which was using the random number generator. When I used it , it didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we use `PrintWriter` over `DataOutputStream` for writing to a file is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346416/what-is-the-difference-between-printwriter-and-dataoutputstream).

```
public static void makefile(double n, String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printWriter.println(rand.nextDouble());  // <--- observe this
    }
    if (printWriter != null) {
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Also,

1. You were not using `rand`.
2. Use `printWriter.println()` that will take care of adding a newline character after each line is written to the file.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

The `DataInputStream` / `DataOutputStream` classes read / write data in binary format. Whereas the Scanner reads the data in text format.

Which means you are writing the binary equivalent of integer 60 to the file, and while reading, you are trying to read the character string "60".

In short:

- Use `DataInputStream` if you are reading data written using `DataOutputStream`.
- Use `Scanner` or `FileReader` if you have used `FileWriter` for writing file.